# What is the difference between open_timeout and read_timeout in sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I need a way to increase the sunspot query timeout in local development. As I was checking the sunspot code I got this code in sunspot.

```
solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production
    read_timeout: 20
    open_timeout: 1
  auto_index_callback: after_commit
  auto_remove_callback: after_commit
```

Here we have two things **read_timeout** and **open_timeout** which looks similar to my problem. Since there is no documentation for it. So, can anybody tell me the purpose of both the things

Comment: Please don't link to plaintext on external sites. If there is some plaintext code or configuration that you are referencing in your question then it must be included directly in your post, not linked to.

Comment: If I am not wrong, `open_timeout` is the timeout configuration when opening a connection, whereas `read_timeout` is for when you requested something from the server.

Comment: @anothermh I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: I gave one. The downvote was for making a question that is not useful. (because it linked to an external site) I left the downvote for not showing any [research effort](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/168).

Comment: @anothermh I did my research but didn't get anything useful. And I have removed the external link and added it in the question

Comment: It took me about a minute and a half to find the linked answer. ‍♂️ It didn't appear to me that you did any research, since you linked to the repo where the answer was found.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. Showing your research and explaining why it didn't help is a good starting point. SO isn't a tutorial site, nor are we here to research for you. With IP requests, `open` timeouts are how long to wait before declaring the connection can't be opened to the host. `read` timeouts are how long to wait when reading stalls before aborting. This is very basic IP communication.

Comment: A quick search on Google of "ruby + read_timeout" returns many hits. Scanning the page shows: https://github.com/ankane/the-ultimate-guide-to-ruby-timeouts.